# Relation between spin degrees of freedom and the dimensions of Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, degrees-of-freedom

I came across a question which reads

> "Suppose the spin degree of freedom of two particles (nonzero rest mass and nonzero spin) is described completely by a Hilbert space of dimension twenty one. Which of the following could be the spin of one of the particles?
>
> (a) 2
>
> (b) 3/2
>
> (c) 1
>
> (d) 1/2"

I am confused about the basics behind this problem; how can we relate spin degrees of freedom with dimensions of Hilbert space?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you could encounter this question without learning about the relation between the spin of a particle and the dimension of its spin space first. Where did you come across it?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I am an undergrad and there's an exam which is set for both undergrads and students doing their masters here in India. I found the question there.

Comment: I remember an exact question in the near past but I can't find it (deleted???). Anyway, in how many ways you could express 21 as product of two integers ???